# Gallian, D&F, or something else?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

I will be taking my university's Honors Abstract Algebra sequence next year, and it uses Dummit & Foote. I was looking for a book to begin studying from this summer, and a friend recommended Gallian's book on the subject. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

These two are best out and out and serve varying purposes gallian for easy read and first understanding. Dummit Foote for expansive knowledge and and thoroughness.You may choose pinter in pplace of gallian as well.

Answer (score 0):

D&F was used in the course Honors Basic Algebra that I took my second year. I think it is generally an excellent book, although it contains no category theory. [A First Course in Abstract Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201763907) by Fraleigh would be an excellent companion to introduce you to category theory.